# How to save data in .xls/.xlsx file to mongodb from angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, json, excel, mongodb

I would like to save data in .xls/.xlsx file to mongodb from angularjs. I have an angularjs frontend, a web service and mongodb. I was thinking I could parse .xls/.xlsx file in angularjs and for each row create a JSON Object. Angularjs would use web service to send the JSON objects to backend to save to mongodb. My concern is if I have many rows that it will take a really long time to process. The other option would be to upload the file to a specific location on server, process the file and then save to mongodb. Is there a better way to achieve the same goals or do you recommend 1 of the options I mentioned? Any help is appreciated.

Regards,

Nilang